# How could a server check the availability of a client?

Tags: java, sockets, http, tcp, callback

I have classic http client/server application where the server serves the clients data at their will but also performs some kind of call-backs to the list of clients' addresses it has. My two questions are :

1- How would the server know if a client is down (the client did not disconnect but the connection got suddenly interrupted) ?

2- Is there a way to know from the server-side if the process at client-side listening on the call-back port is still up (i.e. client call-back socket is still open) ?

Comment: with websockets both sides could ping/pong each other, without only the client to the server

Comment: @HenningLuther : Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- How would the server know if a client is down (the client did not disconnect but the connection got suddenly interrupted) ?

- Option #1: direct communication

  Client tells server "I'm alive" at a periodic interval. You could make your client to `ping` your server at a configurable interval, and if the server does not receive the signal for a certain time, it'll mark the client as down. Client could even tell server more info(e.g. It's status) in each heartbeat if necessary, this is also the way used in many distributed systems(e.g. Hadoop/Hbase).
- Option #2: distributed coordination service

  You could treat all clients connected to a server as a group, and use a 3rd party distributed coordination service like *Zookeeper* to facilitate the membership management. Client registers itself to *Zookeeper* as a new member of the group right after booting up, and leaves the group if it's down. *Zookeeper* notifies the server whenever the membership changes.

> 2- Is there a way to know from the server-side if the process at client-side listening on the call-back port is still up (i.e. client call-back socket is still open) ?

- I think this can only be done by the way `Option #1` listed above. It could be either the way clients tell server "My callback port is OK" at a fixed interval, or the server asks clients "Are your callback port OK?" and wait its response at a fixed interval

Answer (score 0):

You would have to establish some sort of protocol; and simply spoken: the server keeps track of "messages" that it tried to sent to clients.

If that "send" is acknowledged, fine; if not: then the server might do a limited number of retries; and then regard that client as "gone"; and then drop any other messages for that client.

Comment: You are very welcome. And you got some nice answers on top of my brief summary :-)

Answer (score 0):

> 1- How would the server know if a client is down (the client did not disconnect but the connection got suddenly interrupted) ?

A write to the client will fail.

> 2- Is there a way to know from the server-side if the process at client-side listening on the call-back port is still up (i.e. client call-back socket is still open

A write to the client will fail.

The write won't necessarily fail immediately, due to TCP buffering, but the write will eventually provoke retries and retry timeouts that will cause a subsequent read or write to fail.

In Java the failure will manifest itself as an `IOException: connection reset`.